# combine python list elements where value is 1 plus an offset (masking)

Tags: python, list, reduce, masking

The goal is to find a generic method to solve the following task:

I have **two python lists of the same length filled with zeros and ones**:

```
detection = [0,0,1,0]     # only examples, they can be of any length
ground_truth = [0,1,0,0]  # and the ones can be at any indizes
```

and a integer number

```
offset = 1                # this number is also variable
```

The goal is to combine #`offset` elements in `detection` around elements equal to `1`
and then combine the same index elements of `ground_truth` logical `or`, resulting the new lists:

```
detection = [0,1]
ground_truth = [0,1]
```

graphical explanation:

[image]

**Background Info:** The detection / ground truth values belong to a binary classification of a time series and The idea is to have a flexible evaluation that results in a TP if the `detection` fits the `ground_truth` is within a certain range of time steps (=`offset`).

**Additional Example:**

```
offset = 1
detection = [1,0,0,0,1,1,0]
ground_truth = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

would result to:

```
detection = [1,0,1]
ground_truth = [0,0,1]
```

Comment: Why does the detection and ground_truth get truncated to 2 element lists from a 4 element one?

Comment: because the elements around values of 1 get combined / squashed. That is the exact task of the question

Comment: How does it behave when detection is e.g. `[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]`?

Comment: im not sure but in pandas you can use `rolling()` with size 3 - two works with rolling window which has 3 elements - and then you would have to check if middle element is `1` before running some code. Eventually you has to work with slice `[ i : i+3 ]` in `for`-loop which use `range(len(...))`

Comment: in pandas you could use `shift(1)` and `shift(-1)` to put value form previous and next row in new column but in the same row - and then you can work with data in row

Comment: BTW: do you mean `OR` between values in both lists or `OR` between values in second list and value `1` ? If second version then `anything OR 1` gives `anything` and there is no need to use `OR 1`

Comment: each list should be regarded separately. maybe the background info i added answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the ultimate solution.
sub questions that solved it:

- [variable expansion of ones in python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453707/variable-expansion-of-ones-in-python-list)
- [bitwise OR reduction of python lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447168/bitwise-or-reduction-of-python-lists)
- [squash all consecutive ones in a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430679/squash-all-consecutive-ones-in-a-python-list)

Code:

```
# Create Mask from Detection and Offset
w = offset*2 +1
mask = np.convolve(detection, np.ones(w), mode='same').clip(0,1).astype(int)

# Create Soft Detection
soft_detection = mask[~((np.diff(mask,prepend=False)==0) & mask==1)].tolist()

# Create Soft Ground Truth
idx = np.flatnonzero(np.r_[True,np.diff(mask)!=0])
soft_ground_truth = np.bitwise_or.reduceat(ground_truth, idx).tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

My first idea is to use slice `[i-offset:i+offset+1]`

If lists have different lengths then you can get shorter length

```
shorter = min(len(detection), len(ground_truth))
```

To works with lists separatelly you have to first find indexes.

I use `[offset:shorter-offset]` because I assumed that you don't want to check if there is not enought elements on left or right (if there are less elements then `offset`).

```
indexes = [i for i, val in enumerate(detection[offset:shorter-offset], offset) if val == 1]
```

And now you can use indexes

```
for i in indexes:
    #item = detection[i-offset:i] + detection[i+1:i+1+offset]
    # or

    item = detection[i-offset:i+offset+1]
    item.pop(offset) # remove value in the middle

    print('   detection item:', item)
```

I don't know what you try to do with `or` logic - so I skip it.

---

Code - with `offset=2`

```
detection    = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1]   # longer
ground_truth = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]

#detection    = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0]       # shorter
#ground_truth = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1] 

print('   detection:', detection)
print('ground_truth:', ground_truth)

offset = 2
shorter = min(len(detection), len(ground_truth))

indexes = [i for i, val in enumerate(detection[offset:shorter-offset], offset) if val == 1]
print('indexes:', indexes)

for i in indexes:
    #item = detection[i-offset:i] + detection[i+1:i+1+offset]
    # or

    item = detection[i-offset:i+offset+1]
    item.pop(offset) # remove value in the middle

    print('   detection item:', item)

for i in indexes:
    #item = ground_truth[i-offset:i] + ground_truth[i+1:i+1+offset]
    # or

    item = ground_truth[i-offset:i+offset+1]
    item.pop(offset) # remove value in the middle

    print('ground_truth item:', item)
```

Result:

```
   detection: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
ground_truth: [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
indexes: [2, 4, 5]
   detection item: [0, 0, 0, 1]
   detection item: [1, 0, 1, 0]
   detection item: [0, 1, 0, 1]
ground_truth item: [0, 1, 0, 0]
ground_truth item: [0, 0, 0, 1]
ground_truth item: [0, 0, 1, 0]
```

---

Second idea is to use `shift()` to move value from previous/next row to the same row but to new column. But with new information I think it creates too many new columns so I removed it.

---

I was wondering if it could be done with `rolling(window=3)` but I couldn't create solution.

---

Doc: [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Comment: both solutions only works for the exact same lists, the goal is to find a method to do this generic for lists of any length and with ones at any indezies. Also the offset is variable!

Comment: you could write it at start. And you could create example data with different sizes. Create more examples to better describe problem. As for offset `[ i : i + (2*offset) + 1 ]` And I thing both version can give more result if there are more `1` - so only problem can be lists size. But probably `min(len(detection), len(ground_truth))` could resolve it.

Comment: if you want to work with lists separatelly then first code should only find indexes for `1` in first list - and later use this indexes for list. I still don't understand which elements you use in `OR` logic.

Comment: yes exactly, finding the `1` indizes is the first task! 
the offset defines a new range around those indizes, and those values should be squashed / combined to `1` in the `detection` list and the same range of indizes should be combined with a logical `OR` in the ground_truth` list

Comment: Hi thanks for the effort.
But the lists are always of same length, only this length that both have, is variable. Maybe the background info helps: Its the ground truth and the detection of a binary time series classification, so the ones and zeros are "True" / "False" Outcomes of a machine learning model.

Comment: code should work even if you use lists with the same lengths. And you can use longer or shorter list then I used as example - it also should works.

Comment: The code does not solve the problem. Check the additional example i added. Furthermore you should also be able to handle ones at index 0 or at the end of the list.

Comment: I wrote in answer that I assumed that index is skiped because there is no data on the left which you ccould use. And I wrote that I don't understand your `"or" logic`. You have to better describe how you use `or` logic and what to do for index `0`. Simply: you didn't add details so I can't create expected code. Current code only gets `[i-offset: i+offset]` because I don't know how you calculate value with `or` logic.