# squash all consecutive ones in a python list

Tags: python, list, numpy, vectorization

I have variable lists filled with `0s` and `1s`, like:

```
l1 = [1,1,1,0,1,1]
l2 = [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
```

what is the most efficient way to create new lists that squash all consecutive `1s`.

So the result would be:

```
l1_new = [1,0,1]
l2_new = [0,1,0,1,0,0,1]
```

> Hint: numpy/vectorization or some logical operation would be great!

Comment: your second example squashes both 0 and 1 ... why only ask for squished 1s?

Comment: Did you mean you want to squash all consecutive `1s` and `0s`?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Only squash 1s, NOT 0s! that was a mistake in the example result!

Comment: Added timings in my post since it seems you care about efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using with [`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and `bitwise operations`:

```
l1 = [1,1,1,0,1,1]
l2 = [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]

a = np.array(l2)
a[~((np.diff(a,prepend=False)==0) & (a==1))]
# array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Or for the first example:

```
a = np.array(l1)
a[~((np.diff(a,prepend=False)==0) & (a==1))]
#array([1, 0, 1])
```

Comment: perfect, thank you. i have a similar (slighty different) question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447168/manipulate-python-list-depending-on-other-lists-elements/62448122#62448122 maybe you can anwser that aswell

Comment: yw @gustav - will take a look, don't have much time now :)

Answer (score 3):

To leverage NumPy, we would need array, so upon that conversion, we will create an appropriate mask and index -

```
def squash1s(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    m = a==1
    return a[np.r_[True,m[:-1]!=m[1:]] | (a==0)]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [64]: l1 = [1,1,1,0,1,1]
    ...: l2 = [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]

In [65]: squash1s(l1)
Out[65]: array([1, 0, 1])

In [66]: squash1s(l2)
Out[66]: array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1])
```

**Benchmarking**

Since we are concerned with performance efficiency, let's benchmark the NumPy ones, as they should be pretty efficient.

Other proposed solutions

```
# @yatu's solution
def yatu_diff(l):
    a = np.asarray(l)
    return a[~((np.diff(a,prepend=False)==0) & a==1)]

# PaulPanzer's suggestion/soln
def pp_concat(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    return a.repeat(1-(a*np.concatenate([[0],a[:-1]])))
```

Using [`benchit`](https://github.com/droyed/benchit) package (few benchmarking tools packaged together; disclaimer: I am its author) to benchmark proposed solutions.

```
import benchit

funcs = [squash1s, yatu_diff, pp_concat]

# With ~30% 0s
in_ = [(np.random.rand(n)>0.3).astype(int) for n in 10**np.arange(4)]
t = benchit.timings(funcs, in_)
t.plot(logx=True, save='timings30.png')

# With ~70% 0s
in_ = [(np.random.rand(n)>0.7).astype(int) for n in 10**np.arange(4)]
t = benchit.timings(funcs, in_)
t.plot(logx=True, save='timings70.png')
```

With `~30%` 0s :

[image]

With `~70%` 0s :

[image]

Comment: More and more benchmarking tools to choose from :-) Out of curiosity, could you include `a.repeat(1-(a*np.concatenate([[0],a[:-1]])))`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Nice! You gotta post that as a solution. And you gotta try out `benchit` :) Would love some feedback/possible improvements!

Comment: Thanks! Right now I've no time, but will do later. Btw. I suspect mine will scale less good for larger n.

Answer (score 1):

**Given**

```
lst_1 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
lst_2 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
lst_3 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

**Code**

```
def compress_values(seq, value=1):
    """Yield a value in isolation."""

    for here, nxt in zip(seq, seq[1:]):

        if here == nxt == value:
            continue
        else:
            yield here

    yield nxt
```

**Demo**

```
assert [1, 0, 1] == list(compress_values(lst_1))
assert [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] == list(compress_values(lst_2))
assert [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] == list(compress_values(lst_3))
```

---

**Details**

Slide a two-tuple window.  If values are equal to each other and the target `value`, skip.  Otherwise yield values.

An alternative, more general approach:

```
import itertools as it


def squash(seq, values=(1,)):
    """Yield singular values in isolation."""

    for k, g in it.groupby(seq):

        if k in values:
            yield k
        else:
            yield from g
```

Comment: 2nd approach seems to be more natural. Wonder the speed difference between these two. +1

Answer (score -1):

Here is a possible solution

```
arr = [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]

previous_value = None
new_lst = []

for elem in arr:
   if elem != previous_value:
       new_lst.append(elem)
       previous_value = elem

print(new_lst)
```

Where `arr` is any list you want, and it will work with anything including strings.

Comment: answer just removes duplicants, 0s should remain untouched.

Answer (score -1):

Using a while loop,

```
l1 = [1,1,1,0,1,1]
i = 0

while i < len(l1)-1:
    if l1[i] == l1[i+1]:
        del l1[i]
    else:
        i = i+1
print(l1)
```

another one that i found on geekforgeeks is ,

```
from itertools import zip_longest 


test_list = [1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 3, 9] 

res = [i for i, j in zip_longest(test_list, test_list[1:]) 
                                                if i != j]
```

Comment: answer just removes duplicants, 0s should remain untouched.