# bitwise OR reduction of python lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, logical-operators, masking

I have two lists of zeros and ones. Both lists are of same length. The following is just an example, i am looking for a generic solution for lists of any sizes and with zeros and ones at any index.

```
l1 = [1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
l2 = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

The goal is to use the first list `l1` as `mask` to create a new list `l2_new` from `l2` that logicaly `OR` merges all elements of indizes where `l1` is `1` and adopts elements unchanged where `l1` is `0`.

Which would result to:

```
l2_new = [0,0,1]
```

Graphical explanation:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a perfect setup for `np.bitwise_or.reduceat` that does slice-based `OR-ing` -

```
# Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/62430810/ @Divakar
def squash1s_mask(a):
    a = np.asarray(a)
    m = a==1
    return np.r_[True,m[:-1]!=m[1:]] | (a==0)

out = np.bitwise_or.reduceat(l2, np.flatnonzero(squash1s_mask(l1)))
```

Comment: GODLIKE!! So now coming to the last question of this series, maybe you have another numpy magic hand on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407188/combine-python-list-elements-where-value-is-1-plus-an-offset-masking (its the combination of the last question, this one and an additional preceiding task)

Comment: unfortunately this answer is not correct, for  `l2=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`
`l1=[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]` it leads to `[1, 0, 0, 0]`, whereas the correct result would be `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: @gustavz My understanding was that there are islands of 0s and 1s in `l1` and we need to reduce chunks off `l2` based on those islands. So, the number of elements in the output would be same as number of those islands. With your latest setup for `l1`, it has 4 such islands and hence 4 output elements. Did I misunderstand it?

Comment: no the idea is to use `l1` as a mask for `l2`: Where `l1` is `1` the elements in `l2` should be reduced with a logical `OR` - **BUT** where `l1` is `0` all elements of `l2` should remain untouched.

Comment: @gustavz Okay, the idea is that squashing based on your other questioin it seems. Check out edited post.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.
Approach is simple.

Wherever you find 1, check for consecutive 1's and mark the start, end index. OR the entries for this range from l2.

Wherever you find 0, copy the respective element from l2

```
index = 0

prev = 0
res = []
while index < len(l1):
    if l1[index] == 1:
        prev = index
        while index < len(l1) and l1[index] == 1:
            index += 1

        tmp = 0
        for i in range(prev,index):
            tmp = tmp|l2[i]
        res.append(tmp)

    elif l1[index] == 0:
        res.append(l2[index])
        index += 1

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools 
l1 = [1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
l2 = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
pos = [(item, pos) for pos, item in enumerate(l1)]
#[(1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6)]

result = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(pos, lambda x: x[0]):
    if key == 0:
        #if group is all 0 then we don't change anything
        result.extend(l2[g[1]] for g in group)
    else:
        #else do OR operation in current group and append to final list
        current = 0
        for g in group:
            current |= l2[g[1]]
        result.append(current)
result
#[0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help; a simple loop without a lot of additional variables.

```py
l1 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
l2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]

answer = []
or_result = 0
index = 0

while index < len(l1):
    # while 1, OR the elements of l2
    while index < len(l1) and l1[index] == 1:
        or_result ^= l2[index]
        index += 1

    answer.append(or_result)

    # while 0, append the elements of l2 as they are
    while index < len(l1) and l1[index] == 0:
        answer.append(l2[index])
        index += 1

    or_result = 0

print(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer by @ExplodingGayFish, but I apply `groupby` on both lists at the same time, and use functional approach to calculate OR.

```py
from functools import reduce
from itertools import groupby
from operator import or_


def fn(l1, l2):
    result = []

    # group both lists by the values in l1
    for key, group in groupby(zip(l1, l2), key=lambda x: x[0]):
        # extract values from l2
        group_from_l2 = [x[1] for x in group]
        if key == 1:
            # bitwise OR of all values in group_from_l2
            result.append(reduce(or_, group_from_l2))
        else:
            # group_from_l2 unchanged
            result.extend(group_from_l2)

    return result
```

```py
>>> fn([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
[0, 0, 1]
>>> fn([1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1])
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```